# Hadoop: Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)

Tags: hadoop

Each time I run:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

I get the following output:

```
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used%: ï¿½%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)
```

1. There is no data directory in my dfs/ folder.
2. A lock file exists in this folder: in_use.lock
3. The master, job tracker and data nodes are running fine.

Comment: All the nodes on hadoop are up and running fine - name node, job tracker, data nodes.  But the dfsadmin command does not show the data nodes.  Am also not able to connect to data nodes - gives a connection time out error.

Comment: I guess the question now is why are the datanodes not connected to the namenode.

Comment: I have exactly same problem. I checked datanodes logs and the could not connect to master:9000, so I checked ports on master and found this entry: `127.0.1.1:9000`
Should it be sth like `192.168.1.1:9000`?

Comment: @Saeed Adel Mehraba: maybe happens the same to you as here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883564/hadoop-connection-refused-on-namenode/20885555

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa problems seem to be the same. actually I upvoted that question and your answer there.

Comment: Thanks! :) Good to see it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the datanode logs . It will log errors when it is unable to report to namenode . If you post the those errors , people will be able to help ..

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem and when I checked datanodes logs, there were lots of `could not connect to master:9000`, and when I checked ports on master via `netstat -ntlp` I had this in output:

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:9000 ...
```

I realized that I should change my master machine name or change `master` in all configs. I decided to do the first cause it seems much easier.
so I modified `/etc/hosts` and changed `127.0.1.1 master` to `127.0.1.1 master-machine` and added an entry at the end of the file like this:

```
192.168.1.1 master
```

Then I changed `master` to `master-machine` in `/etc/hostname` and restart the machine.
The problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

um...

Did you check firewall?

When i use hadoop, I turn off firewall (iptables -F, in the all nodes)

and then try again.

Comment: This seems like a comment so far.

Comment: I have tried turning the firewall off.  Still no luck.  I am still unable to get the data nodes to connect to the namenode.

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to us, when we restarted the cluster. But after a while, the datanodes were automatically detected. Could be possibly because of block report delay time property.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are errors of namespace id issues in the datanode.
So delete the name dir from master and delete the data dir from the datanodes.
Now format the datanode and try start-dfs. 
The report usually takes some time to reflect all the datanodes.
Even I was getting 0 datanodes, but after some time master detects the slaves.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just solved it.

/etc/hosts of all nodes should look like this:

`127.0.0.1 localhost
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx master
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx slave-1
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx slave-2`

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved the issue by following below steps -

1. Make sure the IP addresses for master and slave nodes are correct in `/etc/hosts` file
2. Unless you really need the data, `stop-dfs.sh`, delete all `data` directories in master/slave nodes, then run `hdfs namenode -format` and `start-dfs.sh`. This should recreate the hdfs and fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just formatting the namenode didn't work for me. So I checked the logs at `$HADOOP_HOME/logs`. In `secondarynamenode`, I found this error:

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
java.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields.
LV = -64 namespaceID = 2095041698 cTime = 1552034190786 ; clusterId = CID-db399b3f-0a68-47bf-b798-74ed4f5be097 ; blockpoolId = BP-31586866-127.0.1.1-1552034190786.
Expecting respectively: -64; 711453560; 1550608888831; CID-db399b3f-0a68-47bf-b798-74ed4f5be097; BP-2041548842-127.0.1.1-1550608888831.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.CheckpointSignature.validateStorageInfo(CheckpointSignature.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:321)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So I stopped hadoop and then specifically formatted the given cluster id:

```
hdfs namenode -format -clusterId CID-db399b3f-0a68-47bf-b798-74ed4f5be097
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's another obscure reason this could happen as well:  Your datanode did not start properly, but everything else was working.

In my case, when going through the log, I found that the bound port, 510010, was already in use by SideSync (for MacOS).  I found this through 
`sudo lsof -iTCP -n -P|grep 0010`, 
But you can use similar techniques to determine what might have already taken your well known data node port.

Killing this off and restarting fixed the problem.

Additionally, if you've installed Hadoop/Yarn as root, but have data dirs in individual home directories, and then try to run it as an individual user, you'll have to make the data node directory public.