# hadoop - Connection refused on namenode

Tags: hadoop, telnet, hadoop-yarn

I've searched web and stackoverflow for a long time but it was not useful.

I have installed hadoop yarn 2.2.0 in 2 node cluster setup. but something goes wrong.
when I start hadoop daemons using start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh on master node, they successfully run in master and slave (my master's hostname is RM and my slave's hostname is slv). they can ssh each other successfully. but when I want to run a job, this error appears:

> 14/01/02 04:22:53 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   14/01/02 04:22:56 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/root/QuasiMonteCarlo_1388665371850_813553673/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1384)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2477)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:555)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:387)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:59582)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1078)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:514)
```

and in datanode log this log exists:

> 2014-01-02 04:40:31,616 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: RM/192.168.1.101:9000
>   2014-01-02 04:40:37,618 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: RM/192.168.1.101:9000. Already tried 0 time(s)$
>   2014-01-02 04:40:38,619 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: RM/192.168.1.101:9000. Already tried 1 time(s)$
>   2014-01-02 04:40:39,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: RM/192.168.1.101:9000. Already tried 2 time(s)$
>   2014-01-02 04:40:40,621 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: RM/192.168.1.101:9000. Already tried 3 time(s)

I checked the 9000 port on the master node and the output is this:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10227/java

I guess the problem is caused by the reason that in the slave node when I

> telnet RM 9000

it says

> Trying 192.168.1.101...
>   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

however

> telnet RM

the output is :

> Trying 192.168.1.101...
>   Connected to RM.
>    Escape character is '^]'.
>   Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
>   RM login:

for additional information my /etc/hosts on master and slave is as below:

> 127.0.0.1    RM|slv  localhost
>
> 192.168.1.101    RM
>
> 192.168.1.103    slv

can anybody suggest me a solution?
any help is really appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Are you running iptables on the namenode? Or something else that would be restricting access to port 9000?

Comment: Good report, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is that your master is listening on `127.0.0.1:9000`, so datanode can't connect because it is not listening at `192.168.1.101:9000` (theoretically, a good place to listen is `0.0.0.0:9000` since avoids this problems, but seems this configuration is not accepted).

Maybe will fix modifying your `/etc/hosts` deleting the first line, or try first just with:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.1.101 RM
192.168.1.103 slv
```

-- edit: read comments bellow

Comment: thanks an ocean for your helpful answer :) after this change telnet works correctly and Namenode and Datanode can connect eachother but when I run a examlpe, this error appears:

Comment: 14/01/03 02:53:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1388746341375_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1388746341375_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1388746341375_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: Call From slv/192.168.1.103 to 0.0.0.0:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
14/01/03 02:53:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0

Comment: the same error in resourcemanager's log. I will discuss nodemanager's log in a new answer below :)

Comment: My fault. Configure it to listen at 192.168.1.101:9000. The idea was theorethical. Just configure RM to listen at 192.168.1.101:9000 and slv to connect to 192.168.1.101:9000 and I think that should work. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I changed

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

in core-site.xml to

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://ip-address:8020</value>
</property>
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. After ran jps, we can see all the namenode and datanode are running up. but cannot see the active node in the web page. And I found I put `127.0.0.1 master` in `/etc/hosts`. After removed it. the slaves can `telnet master 9000`.

My `/etc/hosts` looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

192.168.139.129 slave1

192.168.139.130 slave2

192.168.139.128 master
```